# How to search github issues which does not have a particular label

Tags: github

I want to retrieve list of GitHub issue, which does not have "label_A".

[image]

What is should be the query part I need to be added to the searching bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this `-label:"<label-name>"` into user searching query.

```
-label:"label_A"
```